# Does shared preferences/preference activity allow for enabling/disabling of fragments inside the page?

Tags: java, android, preference, android-sharedpreferences

I have an activity that extends preference activity, to be a settings page. Inside the settings page is an edit text and three different listviews. I want to hardcode the input of the edit text so that when the right "password" (the hardcoded string) is entered, it enables the previously hidden and disabled listviews. Is this possible to happen in same time and how?

```
 private EditText password;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.adminpasswordsetting);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferencesFragment()).commit();

}

public static class MyPreferencesFragment extends PreferenceFragment{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    }
}
private void setAdminSettings(){
    //set the password
    if(password.getText().toString().equals("helloworld")){
    //SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit;
    }
}
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key){

}
```

and my xml preference is just one edittextpreference and three listpreferences

Comment: Yes. Just test the password that was entered, and if it was correct, then perform a FragmentTransaction to add the "hidden" settings to the UI.

Comment: I am new to preference activity, does this happen within the public static class that extends PreferenceFragment? Thanks

Comment: If you are not sure how to do what I am describing, then you likely need to do a little more research on your own before asking for advice here. Working with fragments is very basic, and so is testing the input of an EditText. You might try to code up a solution on your own and then come back here to ask a specific question about your own code if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code probably will not run 'as is' ... so do not copy-paste it.. but I am thinking something alog following lines of code (just as an idea)

```
public class PrefsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    public PrefsActivity() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    ListPreference     lp1 = (ListPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.lp1)); 
    CheckBoxPreference cb2 = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.cb2)); 
    lp1.setEnabled(false);
    cb2.setEnabled(false);
    EditTextPreference etp1 = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.mypassword)); 

    String  mypassword =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString(getString(R.string.mypassword), "0");

  if ("THE_PASSWORD".equals(mypassword)) {
        lp1.setEnabled(true);
        cb2.setEnabled(true);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Since it is in the onCreate() method, would changes be able to occur when inputted? This would definitely work I believe, just curious though that since it is in onCreate() it would run at the beginning and if there is no input yet it would not do anything.

Comment: yes, the way its written - probably it will work (if it will ;-))  as follows : 1. you open preference activity 2.you enter password 3. you close pref activity 4. you reopen it 5. listview becomes enabled... there is huge room for improvements here...but I was just trynig to give the general idea...

Comment: you could  probably also use OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() to catch changes and enable listvew when correct password is entered.